# (Another) Paypal Express API integration issue and interact with js and 'place order' model

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, backbone.js, paypal

I have original fully functional javascript shopping code copied with backbone model call 'Place order';

```
define('models/PlaceOrder',['jquery', 'backbone'],
function($, Backbone) {
    var PlaceOrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: SS.getAPIPageRoot()+'/place_order',
        initialize: function(){
            this.on("sync", this.onSync, this);
        },
        onSync: function(model){
            if(model.has("payment_method") && model.has("payment_data")){
                if(model.get("payment_method") === "paypal" && typeof model.get("payment_data").paypal_form != 'undefined'){
                    $('body').append(model.get("payment_data").paypal_form); //needs to be appending in the DOM for it to work for IE
                    $('#payPalSubmitForm').submit();
                }else if(model.get("payment_method") === "none" && typeof model.get("payment_data").receipt_link != 'undefined'){
                    window.location.href = model.get("payment_data").receipt_link;
                }
                else if (model.get("payment_method") === "paypal_express_checkout" && typeof model.get("payment_data").express_url != 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = model.get("payment_data").express_url;
                } else {
                    model.trigger("error");
                }
            } else {
                model.trigger("error");
            }
        }
    });
    return new PlaceOrderModel();
}
);
```

Some part of SummaryView.js (shortened);

```
define('views/shop/summary/SummaryFooterView',['jquery', 'text!templates/shop/summary/footer.html', 'models/PlaceOrder', 'backbone', 'ss-formview', 'App', 'marionette', 'bootstrap-modal'],
function ($, template, placeOrderModel, Backbone, FormView, App) {
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: template,
        model: shopModel,
        events: {
            'submit form': 'onPlacingOrder',
            'click #terms-checkbox': 'onClickCheckbox',
            'click button.close': 'onCloseAlert'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(shopModel, "change", this.render, this);
            this.listenTo(placeOrderModel, "request", FormView.prototype.onRequest, this);
            this.listenTo(placeOrderModel, "error", FormView.prototype.onModelError, this);
        },

        onClickCheckbox: function(e){
            if(shopModel.get("place_order_enabled")){
                if(this.$(e.currentTarget).prop("checked")){
                    this.$('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass('disabled');
                }else{
                    this.$('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        },
        onPlacingOrder: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            placeOrderModel.save({});
        },
        onCloseAlert: function(e){

        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

            this.$('button[type="submit"]').html(function(){
                return $(this).data("default");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So the essential part in model should be the token Paypal returns  (SetExpressCheckout API call?), because it has buyers info about total amount, address etc.;

```
                    else if (model.get("payment_method") === "paypal_express_checkout" && typeof model.get("payment_data").express_url != 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = model.get("payment_data").express_url;
```

And return JSON;

```
{"payment_data":{"express_url":"https:\/\/www.paypal.com\/cgi-bin\/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-22794774F9358041H&useraction=commit"},"payment_method":"paypal_express_checkout"}
```

However, I don't know, how this model will 'get' or 'catch' that token value from PayPal? Overall this whole API call procedure is hiding somewhere in the original program code (in PHP or maybe). 
My Project is in ASP.NET MVC(server) and standard HTML, javascript (js/Script, without razor-view etc.) as a client.

So the only choice is to make that API procedure myself? What is the easiest way and language (in my case) PHP,ASP.NET#C?

Using this wizard seems to be convenient;

https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

Also can anyone tell, do I have to modify the code if I like the customers have an e-mail receipt(not PayPal-form) from actual program web link, like in the original. I think it's in following part in the same 'Place_order'-model;

```
else if(model.get("payment_method") === "none" && typeof model.get("payment_data").receipt_link != 'undefined'){
                    window.location.href = model.get("payment_data").receipt_link;
```

Any minor advice or hint for getting somewhere is welcome.

Thank You!